# Rendering a Highcharts.js chart uniformly rather than left-to-right

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I want to know if you can change how a highcharts.js chart is rendered. Instead of rendering the chart left-to-right as shown here via [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFKQt/) I'd like to render the chart uniformly on page load.

Meaning, I'd like the entire chart to appear at once rather than be "drawn" left->right.

This is probably one of the [many options](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/) I just can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the following:

```
  plotOptions: {
      series: {
           animation: false
      }
  }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KFKQt/1/)